# Celeryd with django

Tags: django, service, celery, start-stop-daemon

I've been trying to run a celeryd (celery 3.1.25) service for my django project, but when I define

```
CELERYD_USER="www-data"
CELERYD_GROUP="www-data"
```

in `/etc/default/celeryd` which seems to be used a lot, I get the following:

```
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
This account is currently not available.
```

which of course has to do with the ***www-data*** user. If I change the user to, say, "celery", I get a permission denied error on a log file owned by ***www-data***.

Really frustrated...

Comment: So presumably you want to be running celeryd as the "celery" user. Which log file is celeryd trying to touch that is owned by the "www-data" user?

Comment: It is Django project log file. I resolved this by editing the /etc/passwd for www-data.